# Xamarin y WebService JSON no funciona al emularlo en un equipo fisico (ni virtual)

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, xamarin.forms

Mi problema es el siguiente, estoy tratando de hacer una aplicación que se conecte a una base de datos en MSSQLServer y muestre ciertos campos, el Webservice funciona bien, me mandó la respuesta en JSON, ahora en Xamarin cree una aplicación para mostrar este dato que está alojado en el localhost de mi computadora de pruebas por ende la url es la ip de la máquina, en lo que se refiere a código no me muestra ningún error el visual studio pero al ejecutarlo no me muestra nada en la app más que los botones, no sé cual sea el error, adjunto los códigos de la app.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace RestPrueba
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LlenarInventario();
        }
        private async void LlenarInventario()
        {
            HttpClient Cliente = new HttpClient();

            string url = "https://192.168.0.10:80/Wsprueba.php?prod_pos=000450";
            var resultado = await Cliente.GetAsync(url);
            var json = resultado.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            Consulta modelo = Consulta.FromJson(json);
            Inventarios.ItemsSource = modelo.Posts;
        }
    }
}
```

Inventario.cs

```
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class Consulta
    {
        [JsonProperty("posts")]
        public PostElement[] Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class PostElement
    {
        [JsonProperty("post")]
        public PostPost Post { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class PostPost
    {

        [JsonProperty("inv_cod")]
        public string InvCod { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("inv_des_lar")]
        public string InvDesLar { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("inv_cba")]
        public string InvCba { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sal_can")]
        public string SalCan { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sal_cos")]
        public string SalCos { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("gai_pre")]
        public string GaiPre { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Consulta
    {
        public static Consulta FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Consulta>(json, RestPrueba.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this Consulta self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, RestPrueba.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="RestPrueba.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Button Text="Agregar"/>
            <Button Text="Eliminar"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="Inventarios">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding inv_cod}"/>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>   
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Respuesta JSON del servidor

````
{"posts":[{"post":{"0":"000450         ","inv_cod":"000450         ","1":"OMEPRAZOL 28 CAPS","inv_des_lar":"OMEPRAZOL 28 CAPS","2":"0769229152210","inv_cba":"0769229152210","3":".00","sal_can":".00","4":".61000","sal_cos":".61000","5":".8500","gai_pre":".8500"}}]}```
````

Comment: cuando depuras ves que trae la informacion el servicio?

Answer (score 0):

Si tu servicio trae la informacion, lo que te esta faltando en tu constructor es el `BindingContext`.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new modelo.Posts();
        LlenarInventario();
    }
```

Para avisarle a tu vista que modelo de datos le vas a pasar y en tu label funcione la propiedad que tiene `Binding`.

Comment: Al poner esa linea de código que me indicas, me envía un error, al ejecutarlo como lo tengo me da esta excepción Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 'Handshake failed'

Comment: Son errores totalmente diferentes, ese es un error de una clase de internet cuando haces la consulta. Estoy seguro que tenes que pasar el bindingContext con tu modelo. Despues hay que ver en que momento ejecuta ese error. Que error te da con el BindingContext?